# Python: Concise way to toggle boolean "once" (i.e., in one direction)

Tags: python, operators, toggle, binary-operators

I find myself needing to update a boolean variable when something happens for the first time (and only then). Using `var = not var` is out of the question since it would continue flip-flopping every time.

(Sorry for the silly example; I'm struggling to find a more sensible one…)

```
inner_has_been_two = False
for outer in range(5):
    for inner in range(3):
        if inner == 2:

            if not inner_has_been_two:
                inner_has_been_two = True

        print(inner_has_been_two)
```

Let's assume I want to "touch" the variable as little as possible—otherwise I could just overwrite it again and again by simply omitting the innermost `if`-statement.

Basically I'm looking for a more terse, pythonic way to emulate (the binary versions of the ternary conditional operator, like) the Elvis operator (`?:`) or a null coalescing operator (e.g. `??`; varies upon language).

Any ideas on how to keep it short(er) and clear?

Comment: Oh, just remembered. I even toyed around with the idea of writing: `inner_has_been_two = True if not inner_has_been_two`. It's One line instead of two; but still not all too elegant, imho.

Comment: inner_has_been_true |= True

Comment: @Prune: What exactly does that mean?

Comment: @zondo `|` does a "bitwise or".

Comment: @Prune: Yeah, I realized what it meant from your answer.  I should have known that it was a shortcut for `inner_has_been_true = inner_has_been_true | True`.  I just don't often use bitwise operations, so it didn't occur to me that they could be handled the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting it to True each time is certainly fast: a single machine cycle, likely easy to parallel process.  If you want something logically like what you were trying to do:

```
inner_has_been_true |= True
```

This is also a single-cycle instruction, a "bit set" operation.  It's the shorthand for

```
inner_has_been_true = inner_has_been_true | True
```

Comment: `inner_has_been_true |= True` is shorthand for `inner_has_been_true = inner_has_been_true | True` which is not equivalent to `inner_has_been_true = inner_has_been_true or True`

Comment: Thanks—that's what I'd been looking for!

Comment: @Alex -- thanks.  I corrected my answer.  I've been typing too much user documentation this week, I think.